# What is the difference between the coxph and cph functions for calculating Cox's proportional hazards model?

Tags: r, rms

I am trying to analyse a dataset (`veteran`, in package `survival` in R) with survival analysis. I found the function `cph` in package `rms`, which seems like different to `coxph`. What is the difference between these two functions?

Also, in this example,

```
model1<-cph(with(data=veteran,Surv(time,status)~rcs(age,4)+trt),x=TRUE,y=TRUE)
```

what's does `rcs(age,4)` mean?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you look at the source code for `cph`, you can see that it calls `coxph`.  Without looking into it properly, I guess that `cph` is a convenience wrapper to `coxph` to make it behave similarly to the other regression functions in the `rms` package.

Answer (score 4):

RCS = restricted cubic spline.
You can find the function's help file by looking at `help(package="rms")`

Here's an excerpt of the source code, so you can see where the `cph` function calls the `coxph.fit` function (the guts of `coxph` in the `survival` package)

```
>cph

[...]
    if (nullmod) 
        f = NULL
    else {
        ytype = attr(Y, "type")
        fitter = if (method == "breslow" || method == "efron") {
            if (ytype == "right") 
                coxph.fit
            else if (ytype == "counting") 
                survival:::agreg.fit
            else stop(paste("Cox model doesn't support \"", ytype, 
                "\" survival data", sep = ""))
        }
        else if (method == "exact") 
            survival:::agexact.fit

[...]

    class(f) = c("cph", "rms", "coxph")
    f
}
```

Both `cph` and `coxph` give the same results as far as coefficients:

```
>library("survival")
>library("rms")
>
>x = rbinom(100, 1,.5)
>t = rweibull(100, 1, 1)
>
>m1 = coxph(Surv(t)~x)
>m2 = cph(Surv(t)~x)
>m1$coefficients
        x 
0.2226732 
>m2$coefficients
        x 
0.2226732
```

But you can see that the authors of the `cph` function have added some extra components to the results to fit their needs. Thus `cph` will be useful if you need one of those extra features, but otherwise, `coxph` will do just fine.

```
>attributes(m1)
$names
 [1] "coefficients"      "var"               "loglik"            "score"            
 [5] "iter"              "linear.predictors" "residuals"         "means"            
 [9] "concordance"       "method"            "n"                 "nevent"           
[13] "terms"             "assign"            "wald.test"         "y"                
[17] "formula"           "call"             

$class
[1] "coxph"

>attributes(m2)
$names
 [1] "coefficients"      "var"               "loglik"            "score"            
 [5] "iter"              "linear.predictors" "residuals"         "means"            
 [9] "concordance"       "terms"             "n"                 "call"             
[13] "Design"            "assign"            "na.action"         "fail"             
[17] "non.slopes"        "stats"             "method"            "maxtime"          
[21] "time.inc"          "units"             "center"            "scale.pred"       

$class
[1] "cph"   "rms"   "coxph"
```